# Parsing list of strings ending with double NULL

Tags: c++, string, null

How to parse in c++ list of null-terminated Unicode strings where the list is terminated with two NULL characters?

Comment: Can you be more specific? The list of strings is terminated by a "string" of two null characters? Unicode? If it's utf8, there is no such thing as a string of two null characters.

Comment: What kind of strings ? Proper C++ strings, or *old skool* C strings ?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I think you need to read a text book on C. Try Kernigan and Ritchie,  The C Programming Language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this little example on [Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx) (which, perhaps not surprisingly, is the first find in Google for "double null terminated string"):

> This reinterpretation of a double-null-terminated string as really a
>   list of strings with an empty string as the terminator makes writing
>   code to walk through a double-null-terminated string quite
>   straightforward:

```
> for (LPTSTR pszz = pszzStart; *pszz; pszz += lstrlen(pszz) + 1) {  ...
> do something with pszz ... }
```

The LPTSTR and lstrlen are wrappers which change depending on whether or not _UNICODE is set.

Comment: The URL to the blog has changed. 

Blog title: "What is the format of a double-null-terminated string with no strings?"

Blog URL on 2022-08-29: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091008-00/?p=16443

Format of a  double-null-terminated string: "Hello\0world\0\0"

Answer (score 1):

You simply build a list of strings and abort when one is empty:

```
std::vector<std::string> result;
result.push_back( std::string() );
while (std::cin) {
    char c = std::cin.get();
    if ( c == 0 ) { 
        if ( result.back().empty() ) { result.pop_back(); return; }
        else result.push_back(std::string()); }
    } else {
        result.back().push_back(c);
    }
}
```